Ac Resonant Test System Problem
We purchased an AC resonance test system. However, we encountered an issue when attempting to perform calibration. Although we applied 5 kV from the device, we observed 8.57 kV at the output. Initially, the voltage difference between what we set on the device and what we measured at the output was about 10%. Later, this discrepancy increased to 30%, 40%, and even up to 60%.
We tried different voltage levels, but the difference never dropped below 40%. Interestingly, the resonance frequency of the device closely matches the frequency at the output, but there is a significant difference in voltage levels.
We suspected the capacitive voltage divider, tested it, but it appeared to be functioning normally. While we have no issues with voltage amplification, the difference between the device's voltage and the output voltage we read is very large.
I have attached images showing the settings we used, mostly in the "auto" mode, and the measurements we took. In these attachments, you can also see the device's voltage and the output voltage we observed.
Could you please assist us in resolving this issue?




I'm adding the schematic, but the only difference from the diagram is that we connected it to the voltage divider used for calibration instead ofcompensation capacitor.
The original diagram is located at this address, but I have edited it.
https://manuals.plus/huazheng/hzxb-160kv-hv-series-resonance-test-device-manual#MTguMTU3LjEwNS4xODI7NjYuMjQ5Ljc5LjYsIDE3Mi42OC4xNzQuMTgzLCAxMDQuMTMxLjE2OS4xMTUsIDEzNS4xMjUuMzYuNzcsIDE3Mi43MC4yNTAuNTU7MTM1LjEyNS4zNi43NzsxMzUuMTI1LjM2Ljc3OzEzNS4xMjUuMzYuNzc=

Could you supply a schematic for your setup? Note that serries LC circuits can produce voltages higher than the voltage they are driven by.

@Math Keeps Me Busy
Is there a mistake in the calibration circuit? Could you explain it please?

What test results are you expecting to achieve?
For series resonant gain, it is related to \$Q=\sqrt{L/C} /2R\$ while R = Vout/Iout added to the series Rs.  So Iout will affect the gain.   Saturation of the core can also reduce the Q as L reduces over voltage, if there is Fe involved by adding DC bias.
As you define your test circuit better, this answer will expand.

We expected the voltage we increased after series resonance in our device to remain almost the same. Initially, the voltage difference we observed in the device and the output was around 10%, but later it increased to 50-60%. Such a large difference seemed abnormal to us

Amplitude changes can be explained by measured values of LC, L/C, Q, Rp, Lm  or fo, power levels, temperature changes.  Did you measure any of these?  Damping factors don't just jump for no reason, unless there was PD activity. Your measurements are somewhat lacking details

Did you degauss core?

The transformer we are using is an excitation transformer with a 0-400 V input and single-phase outputs of 1.5 kV, 3 kV, and 6 kV. We are increasing the voltage using series resonance. We haven’t eliminated the residual magnetism yet; we can try what you suggested. Do you think residual magnetism could affect the output voltage to this extent? Thank you very much.

It depends on how much residual and excitation voltage p.u. . I once used a Li Ion battery to measure L=VdI/dt and found on a 5MVA I could degauss in the factory with a 18650 battery by measuring current thru both polarities where dI/dt begins to rise  in each polarity limit then reverse the voltage and discharge time 50%.  But if residual mag is high then yes it will affect results if transformer has low margin to saturation. Use an AM radio over Trafo  to listen for PD activity, which also is bad. (tick tick)

We will short-circuit and ground all terminals of the transformer (for demagnetization purposes). If necessary, we will also use the Raytech DC resistance measurement device to assist with demagnetization. Additionally, instead of using the calibration company's voltage divider, we will use a 36 kV voltage transformer. By reading the voltage from its secondary, we will observe whether the previous issue persists.
